# menu not dropping down on hover, only dropping down when menu button clicked

Tags: menu, conflict

The yootheme Joomla 3 template I bought works fine on the template sellers site, but when I installed it and edited it the menu is not functioning correctly.  The drop down on the menu only works when I click a menu button.

AquaponicsUS.com

It is supposed to dropdown on hover.

This was my last allowed website on my yootheme subscription that came just before the subscription ended so no support.

Answer (score 0):

Most youtheme templates come with settings and configuration. Check in the Template Manager and that Theme if you can find some Template Settings for this theme. If you see the same template on their site working with hover effect then it most certainly must be a setting.

Does the template package come with documentation inside? Please check in the package itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There is no documentation in the package files.   There is no setting I can find.  I have searched carefully.  Is it possibly a JS conflict?